# How to build a binary debian package

Tags: build, package, binary, debian

I'm trying to use:

```
dpkg-deb --build --root-owner-group myapp_1.0-1_amd64
```

to build a binary package for "myapp". The directory structure is:

```
myapp_1.0-1_amd64 

    DEBIAN

        control

    usr

        local

           bin

               myapp
```

A package file is created and it will install. I next tried to use dpkg-shlibdeps to get a list of dependencies. This command expects debian/control (note the case) to be in the path.

If I rename DEBIAN to debian and add a SOURCE directive to the control file then

```
dpkg-shlibdeps -O /usr/local/bin/t
```

results in

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: binaries to analyze should already be installed in their  
package's directory
shlibs:Depends=libc6 (>= 2.34), libmariadb3 (>= 3.0.0)
```

Adding this dependency and upping the version number and rebuilding the package does not (when installing the package) result is a missing dependency error.

So I have two questions.

Why does dpkg-deb expect a DEBIAN directory while pkg-shlibdeps expects a debian (lower case).

Why doesn't the dependency check work?

I feel like I'm using the wrong approach or perhaps the wrong tools. My hope was to keep this simple. Our app is actually quite large (many files) that (1) doesn't build with autotools and (2) doesn't include all the source. For this use case I thought a binary package build would be appropriate. Set me straight if otherwise.

Comment: A depend on literal `Depend: ${shlibs:Depends}` should be sufficient. Non-autotools is ok, override the [rules](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/11.2/debian/rules) with targets. Not sure what (2) means and how it can be built in that case.

Comment: I'll try that. I did find this https://github.com/FooBarWidget/debian-packaging-for-the-modern-developer which points to the confusion on debian vs DEBIAN.

Comment: I'd start with a more [modern and updated guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/devel-manuals#debmake-doc).

Comment: Well, I can see where this is the thing to do for single exec or a few files. However, my application is actually 100's of executables and miscellaneous files in a nested directory structure. Don't know but I'm guessing the intent for package use doesn't handle this situation well. Comments welcome.